# Any downside in using FileStream directly in webservice?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, filestream

I have a small working REST webservice which delivers a file. Is there any downside in using a FileStream directly or is it advisable (and why) to write the file to a MemoryStream first?

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet]
public Stream GetFile(string filepath)
{
    //...
    Stream stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    return stream;
}
```

I am thinking if there could be cases where for a slow connection or whatever reason this could cause problems?

//edit, as it was suggested below: Wrapping the stream into a using() block does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Basically no downside though there are some limitations, say when you use session base binding, as documented in

[Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Regarding to file stream, because of the spinning nature of hard drive, concurrent access might slow things down unless you have RAID. So you may consider some caching solutions, some sort of buffering?

Comment: Thanks, that shed some light on this. I'll probably set up a debug session some time to see when the file is actually released, ie the FileStream is being closed.

Comment: In the how to enclosed in your link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010(v=vs.110).aspx) they also use a simple FileStream - even when actually streaming. So this practice can't be too bad :)

Comment: Your last paragraph really has nothing to do with `FileStream` itself, it has to do with any disk or network access - even a database query, at least most of the time. It makes no difference if you return the `FileStream` directly or copy it somewhere else. Caching obviously can help, but caching can help *anywhere* that you have I/O access.